# How i can delete image from Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter

I would like do delete an image from Firebase Storage.

I tried this but it's not working for me

```
await _storage.child('gs://flutter-firebase-636d0.appspot.com/e-commerce/header_image/img1.jpg').delete();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you can delete the image with download URL easily

```
String imageUrl = 'here goes image url';
StorageReference ref = await FirebaseStorage().getReferenceFromUrl(imageUrl);
ref.delete();
```

**Update**

```
FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(imageUrl).delete();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't put the `gs://` url inside the child method as a parameter. However, you can feed this to the `storageBucket` property of the FirebaseStorage class.

```
final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'gs://flutter-firebase-636d0.appspot.com/');
```

Then you can delete your image like this:

```
onPressed: () async{
        await storage.ref().child("e-commerce/header_image/img1.jpg").delete();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Feb 2021:**

```
 Future<void> removeImageFromUrl(String url) async {
        try {
          Reference ref = await FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url);
          await ref.delete();
        } catch (e) {
          print('Failed with error code: ${e.code}');
          print(e.message);
        }
    }
```

The url in the above method is the one that is fetched after storing the image to the bucket.

```
eg:
 https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxx.appspot.com/o/bucket%2xxxx?alt=media&token=xxxx
```

Reference:
https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the path to the file as the argument of the child like this:

```
await _storage.child('sample/path/to/the/image.jpg').delete();
```